# Как привязать модальное окно?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
$('#sendApp').click(function () {
    var mail=$('.mail').val(), ms=$('.ms').val();
    if (!mail.match(/^[-._a-z0-9]+@(?:[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/)) {
        alert('Введите корректный email');
        return false;
    }
    else if(ms.length<5){
        alert('Длинна текста должна быть более 5 символов');
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $.post(
            "/send_t.php",  {
                ms:ms,
                mail:mail,
                name:$('.name').val()                 
            }, res
        );
    }
});

function  res(data) {
    console.log(data);
    if(data==='+'){
        $('body').append('<div style="width: 482px; height: 192px; background-color: white; position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%;">Все ок!</div>')
    }
    else  alert("Что-то пошло не так")
}
```

Есть такой скрипт обратной связи, когда письмо успешно отправлено, надо выводить модальные окно, что все успешно, как его вывести? Допустим у меня уже есть код html этого сообщения, как при нажатии на крестик сделать что бы оно закрылось, ну и что бы все затемнялось и было заблокировано, как в модальных окнах. Пробовал добавить див с помощью абсолюта разместить по середине, но почему-то блок появлется вверху страницы, а не на той секции, где была нажата кнопка отправки.

Comment: добавляйте див в помощью position:fixed;

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите [jQueryUI.dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/). Хорошая штука. Может ещё что-то полезное для себя найдёте